# Divergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{1+x^n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have searched on stack exchange for 20 mins to find the behaviour of this series$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{1+x^n}}$$ I couldn't find an answer relavent for me. I found that this series converges for $x \in [1,\infty)$ and uniformly converges for $[1+\epsilon,\infty)$. I also understood how to prove these. But i didn't understand how divergence can be established for $ x \in (-\infty,-1)$.

i tried $x =-2$ and i got an alternating series with monotonously decreasing terms and limit of $n^{th}$ term going to infinity. Isn't it by Leibniz test convergent? Where did i go wrong? Please tell me how to prove the divergence.

Answer (score 1):

The sum does converge absolutely and uniformly for $x \in (-\infty, -1-\epsilon]$ and converges absolutely for $x \in (-\infty, -1)$

The key point is that with $x \lt -1$ you have $$\left|\dfrac{1}{1+x^n}\right| \le 
\left(\tfrac{|x|+1}{|x|-1}\right) \dfrac{1}{1+|x|^n}$$ and then you already have the results you found for $x \gt 1$

Comment: $$\left|\dfrac{1}{1+x^n}\right| \le 
\left(\tfrac{|x|+1}{|x|-1}\right) \dfrac{1}{1+|x|^n}$$  can you please explain this part in more detail.

Comment: @VibinNarayanan  For $x \lt -1$ the difficulty is with odd $n$. But you can say  $\dfrac{\left|\frac{1}{1+x^n}\right|}{\frac{1}{1+|x|^n}}$ which for odd $n$ is $\dfrac{(-x)^n+1}{(-x)^n-1}$ is maximised when $n=1$ being $\dfrac{-x+1}{-x-1}$